# Go bug tracking / report system?

Tags: bug-tracking, go

Where can I file bug reports for the Go language? I mean reports about a crashing compiler or something else about Go that does not work as advertised. It would also be interesting to just read through them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Go issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list)

Answer (score -1):

As of 2010-05-07 there's only one remaining bug in the current release's test suite (AMD/64 version) and that has to do with structure alignment not being "optimal".  Some members are stored wider than they really need to be.  If you've not seen it yet I recommend a good look at http://www.golang.org, and perhaps searching the archives of the mailing list linked there.

Hotei